# What is the distribution of the combination of two indepenently and normally distributed random variables?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, random-variables

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent random variables such that $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_1, \sigma_1)$ and $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_2, \sigma_2)$. In addition, let $Z=X^2+XY$ be the combination of these two random variables, then what is the PDF or CDF of $Z$?

Honestly, I know what to do with $Z=X + Y$ or $Z=XY$ since $X$ and $Y$ are independent. However, things are different here because both $X^2$ and $XY$ depend on $X$, and unfortunatly, I have totally no idea  about how to deal with the dependency.

Comment: $X+XY=X(1+Y)$. $X$ and $1+Y$ are independent.

Comment: @AlexanderGrey ahhh... sorry for that I have made a mistake. Its $X^2 + XY$ not $X+XY$.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to get the distribution function of $Z=X^2$.

Knowing that $X\sim f_X(x)$, if $z>0$, then

$F_Z(z) = P(Z\le z) = P(X^2 \le z) = P(-\sqrt{z}\le X\le \sqrt{z}) = F(\sqrt{z}) - F(-\sqrt{z}).$

Taking derivative, we have

$f_Z(z) = \frac{f_X(\sqrt{z}) + f_X(-\sqrt{z})}{2\sqrt{z}}.$

If $z\le 0$, then $F_Z(z) = P(Z\le z) = P(X^2\le z) = 0$, we have
$f_Z(z) = 0$.

Taking $f_X(x) = N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ in to the above formula we get the desire result.

Comment: But what I want to know is the distribution of $Z=X^2+XY$ instead of $X^2$